# Edit VSCode JSON Settings NOT the Gui Settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are many tutorials out there that give info about editing VSCode's JSON settings.

How do you SKIP the Gui setting and go straight to the JSON edit page?

Answer (score 0):

File → Preferences → Settings → search JSON